# Adwords Api on AppEngine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-ads-api

I am trying to use Adwords Api on Google App Engine (Java 1.7.7).

I tried to use the default dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
        <artifactId>ads-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
        <artifactId>adwords-axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

They work fine on the devserver, but fail in production (what is strange by itself).

After googling around and not finding anything I did another MavenSearch and found:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
        <artifactId>adwords-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried to use that library what somehow looked good.

I switched my code to use 
import com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.v201302.*
which were provided by the Api.

But stuff breaks miserably even on the devserver: E.g java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.xml.internal.ws").

It also breaks in production - for instance:
java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.address

Just to sum up:

My application runs nicely and works. But not in AppEngine production. And not with adwords-appengine.

Is there a good tutorial how to setup ads-lib on AppEngine? Seems that the official site does not feature a single reference to a tutorial (or even the lib). I am wondering if anyone is using com.google.api-ads' adwords-appengine at all.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the "solution" is the following:

1) Use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
    <artifactId>adwords-appengine</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Make sure you are using only jaxws - for instance:

```
com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.v201302.*
```

3) Watch out for "real" problems on production. Many error messages on App Engine are just warnings and can be ignored. Especially watch out for BeansUtils exceptions and fix them in your code. Some Adwords classes use BeanUtils (and reflection) and do not run on AppEngine. I was able to easily fix those problems in my code.

4) The AppEngine:devserver 1.7.7 is broken because it will throw a lot of

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied exceptions.
```

BUT

in production these errors do not occur. I am using Ninja to develop my app, so I can easily switch away from the official devserver. But if you cannot switch away you are stuck I guess. Filed a bug at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9213

**UPDATE**

The Adsense AppEngine teams were really responsive and the issue will be fixed in the next devserver 1.7.8.

Comment: 3 quick updates: 1. Google is working on the issue. Yea! 2. Switching back to java 6 fixes the problem on the devserver! 3. As rrch pointed out - flag --jvm_flags=-D--enable_all_permissions=true disables the security checks and therefore make it run on the devserver with java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the security checks in the dev appserver with this command line option:
  --jvm_flags=-D--enable_all_permissions=true